# AWS RDP client error An internal error has occurred

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp

I have a Windows instance on AWS with Remote Desktop connection.
Till yesterday RDP client was working fine today suddenly it started showing the "an internal error has occurred" .
I have tried the following:

- Reboot the instance
- Allow Firewall to connect
- Restarted RDP service
- Disabled VPN
- 3389 port is open

Nothing seems to be working, What can be done to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on two Windows 2019 servers and was getting the "an internal error has occurred" error message back on the first RDP attempt, but if I re-attempted to RDP immediately afterwards, it would work just fine. For me, all it took was rebooting the Windows servers and RDP functioned like normal again. Since rebooting didn't seem to work in this case, it could be a DNS issue. Try attempting to connect using the IP address instead of the machine name and/or perform an ipconfig /flushdns from the command prompt (in administrator mode).

Here is a link I found to some additional suggestions/ideas you could look at:
[https://theitbros.com/rdp-an-internal-error-has-occurred/#:~:text=Open%20the%20properties%20of%20your%20RDP%20connection%20in,authentication%20fails%20to%20Connect%20and%20don%E2%80%99t%20warn%20me](https://theitbros.com/rdp-an-internal-error-has-occurred/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20properties%20of%20your%20RDP%20connection%20in,authentication%20fails%20to%20Connect%20and%20don%E2%80%99t%20warn%20me).